# Can i change wordpress plugins path in wp_options

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have a `multisite` installation and i want create a plugins and uploads directory for every site , is it possible to change site plugin and uploads path from `wp_options` ?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question correctly. You want to control for each site the plugins and uploads?

Comment: yes , i want create diffrent directories with diffrent names for every site. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that a `multisite`is supposed to only use one directory for uploads and one for plugins. Thats the purpose of it. 
However, you can install the plugin `plugin organizer`. With that you can use plugins individually for each page.
If you need own plugins and upload directories I suggest that you make one wordpress site for each site instead of a `multisite`